# Search dot files in current directory

Tags: grep

What's a simple way to grep just the dot files (.*) in the current directory ($HOME)?  Using

**grep target .***

returns a lot of nonsense:

**grep: foo is a directory.**

I don't want to see the nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has an option `-s` :

```
 -s, --no-messages
              Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
```

so you can just do `grep -s 'target' .*`